# Synonymize [ide] and [development-environment]

Tags: support, synonym-request

I think that [development-environment](/questions/tagged/development-environment) should be a synonym of [ide](/questions/tagged/ide). The acronym IDE stands for "Integrated Development Environment". Their tag wikis are similar...

[ide](/questions/tagged/ide)

> a computer program that facilitates software-development by providing features beyond that of a simple text editor

[development-environment](/questions/tagged/development-environment)

> extends a text editor by providing built-in hooks

IDE should definitely be the master tag, as its wiki is much more informative and there are 4 times as many questions tagged.

Comment: These are not the same thing. I don't use an IDE, but I certainly have a development environment... I am a developer. The tag wiki for [tag:development-environment] is narrower than I expect it to be... the word *Integrated* should go.